# how can we edit (change products color/size ) on an order with status "processing"?

Tags: magento2, backend, order-status

When an order get status "processing" there is no "edit" button in backend.

How can we edit an order with status "processing". ex. change color/size on products. (before the invoice is created) ?

Comment: By default, you cannot edit order like that. But, you can do these steps: Cancel the order, create the new one.

Answer (score 2):

We solved this issue with "Order editor" from mageworx.

Answer (score 0):

At default Magento, you cannot edit order item detail at order details page.

**Only at pending state, you can change  Customer address details.**